# Image overflowing bounds with clip to bounds set

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that has an image view within it:

[image]

Which has the following bounds for its large image:

[image]

And has the following setting:

[image]

The code around this is pretty simple, its using the [KingFisher library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to fetch the image:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let element = comments[indexPath.row]
        ...
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CommentImagePostCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CommentImagePostCell")


        if (element.Image != "" ){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentImagePostCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentImagePostCell

            let urlString = API.baseUploadURL + element.Image
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            cell.imageView!.kf.setImage(with: url)

      ...
     }
     ...
}
```

However the above code ends up with the image loading in an unclipped manner, seems to complete ignore the bounds? This works else where within my app so I don't think its something wrong with the library and just something I'm missing?

Anyone have any idea why its not clipping?

[image]

Comment: Use the View Debugger and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common mistake:

**`UITableViewCell`** has its own **`imageView`** property and this is what you are currently setting the image to.

Replace:

```swift
cell.imageView?.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

With:

```swift
cell.imgView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

Rename your **`UIImageView`** to something like **`imgView`** and update the code, as above, and you should be good.

Comment: This is why I love stack overflow, such a simple mistake but I would have never spotted it! thank you!

Comment: ^^ Seriously! Thanks!